# Magnificent necklace combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

We have the following problem:

You have to make a necklace with pearls.
Minimum number of pearls that can be used is `1` and maximum is `n`.
Each pearl has a ***magnificence coefficient*** and the necklace should be such that the pearls are in strict ascending order of their magnificence.
Find the number of necklaces that can be formed with such condition.
Input given is `n` (no of pearls), lowest magnificence `lm` and highest magnificence `hm`.

Example:
n = 1
LM = 8
HM =9

Answer = 2

There can be 2 cases, one necklace with pearl 8 and one with pearl 9.

One solution that I can think of is as follows:

Let `ans(n, lm, hm)` be the answer for `n` pearls such that all pearls are in the range `lm - hm`.

Now, `ans(n, lm, hm) = ans(n-1, lm+1, hm) + ans(n-1, lm+2, hm) +ans(n-1, lm+3, hm) + ans(n-1, lm+1, hm) +  ... ans(n-1, hm-1, hm)`

Because in the first slot, we can either put pearl `lm` or `lm+1` or `lm+2` ... till `hm-1`.

And of course `ans(n, lm, hm)` would be 0 if `n > hm - lm + 1`.

My question is that is there a closed-form solution to this problem?

Comment: Note that there is no need to give both the $l_m$ and the $h_m$. Just their difference is enough. Or, perhaps more fittingly, their difference plus $1$, as that's the number of available magnificence coefficients. Where is this problem from, by the way? The way you've written it, it looks more like a programming exercise than a math exercise.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. My friend was asked this question in an interview for a software developer role.

Answer (score 2):

let us take a good example to work with n = 3,LM = 6,HM = 9. from the question we can deduce one thing that we'll have to find the necklace combinations for each n ie `n -> 1 to 3` and them add them together. lets do this for n = 1 and n = 2 manually and look for a pattern

I'm going to list out all combinations grouped by their first number

```
for n = 1

6 : {6}
7 : {7}
8 : {8}
9 : {9}

for n = 2 

6 : {6,6} {6,7} {6,8} {6,9}
7 : {7,7} {7,8} {7,9}
8 : {8,8} {8,9}
9 : {9,9}
```

did you see it ? for n = 2, 7 only combined with numbers in the previous group which are smaller or equal Than it ie 7,8,9. since the ans of our current state can be generated by the previous state we use dp. here is the dp table for the given example

```
   6  7  8  9

1  1  1  1  1

2  1  2  3  4

3  1  3  6  10
```

here the row's represent the necklace length and column's represent unique pearl number.
for example dp(2,8) represent the combinations of a necklace of size 2 and having 8 as the last element which is generated by adding `dp[2-1][6]...dp[2-1][8]`. here is the code

```
int sol(int n, int lm,int hm){
    
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n,vector<int>(hm-lm+1,1));
    int ans = hm-lm+1 + n-1;

    for(int i=1;i<dp[0].size();i++){
        dp[0][i]+=dp[0][i-1];
    }

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<dp[0].size();j++ ){
            ans += dp[i-1][j];
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j]+dp[i][j-1];
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```